# how to update specific cell in data grid view using SQL and VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to update a specific cell in `datagridview` using `vb.net` and `sql` ( or any other method)
I am using this code to split somme strings and save it into database.

```
  Private Sub SalveazaData()
    Dim list As String() = rtbComData.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
    SmdDataDataSet1.SearchAdrese.Rows.Clear()
    SmdTableTableAdapter.ClearSearchAdrese()
    Me.SearchAdreseTableAdapter.Update(Me.SmdDataDataSet1.SearchAdrese)
    For Each Row As String In list
        If Not (Row = "AT+DSCAN" Or Row = "OK" Or Row = "" Or Row = "AT+RSSI") Then

            Dim s As String() = Split(Row, "|")
            Dim aRow As smdDataDataSet1.smdTableRow = SmdDataDataSet1.smdTable.NewsmdTableRow()
            aRow.Model = s(0)
            aRow.AdresaUnica = s(1)
            aRow.StatusModul = "ACTIVE"
            Try
                SmdDataDataSet1.SearchAdrese.Rows.Add(s(1))
                SmdDataDataSet1.smdTable.Rows.Add(aRow)
            Catch ex As Exception

                Dim u As String
                u = SmdTableTableAdapter.UpdateInactivActiv()
            End Try
        End If
    Next
    'selectzr()
    salveaza()
    status()

    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

The table has the columns

```
 Model | Adresa Unica | Status | time | InstAddress |
  ZR      123456         active   
  ZR      654321         active
```

What i want to do is update the row with the address "123456" or "654321" and write in their specific cell ,  in this case the cell from the column  | time | a value .
Can you please help me .?

Comment: still nothing?  to be more specific ... i need any method to update the specific cell . i think i can start from there and work my way up .:)

Answer (score 0):

I have made some digging and i have fund an answer.
please see below the code i've used in my application

```
Private Sub GroupCommandRtime()
    Dim list As String() = rtbComData.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())`enter code here`
    Dim ListaAdrese As List(Of String) = GetAdreseID()
    For Each Row As String In list
        For Each _Adresa As String In ListaAdrese
            If Not (Row = "at+remote=" Or Row = "AT+RSSI" Or Row = "OK") Then
                Try
                    Dim s As String() = Split(Row, " ")
                    Dim con As New SqlConnection
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
                    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database\smdData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE smdTable SET datetime='" + s(3) + "' WHERE AdresaUnica = '" + s(0) + "'"

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    Me.SmdTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SmdDataDataSet1.smdTable)
                    DataGridView1.Refresh()

                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End If
        Next
    Next


End Sub
```